# Find Pictures in Web?

Tags: .net, image, watermark

I want to have a tool what is able to find my pictures in web.

That means I have pictures with a watermark from me inside the picture and I need to be able to scan webpages (and all pictures in it) and see if my picture is online on this webpage.

Background is, that someone used my picture (with a watermark from me) and win a price with it!

To get all pictures from a specific site is very easy.
The question is, how can I look inside a picture for my watermark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to scan the entire internet looking for pictures which look like yours? That's a lot of work, why not use something like [TinyEye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinEye) to do the hard work for you? I think you've really underestimated what's involved in doing it yourself.